# div id in php echo doesn't work

Tags: php

For a school project I need to make a site. I want to make a div inside an echo in PHP but somehow it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" 
    sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-16x16.png" 
    sizes="16x16" />
    <title>MLB: Major League Baseball</title>
    <link href="css folder/MLBstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css"/>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="titel">    

           <img class="MLBTitel"  src="./images/MLBtitel.jpg" alt="MLBTitel" >
           <div id="titeltekst">
               MAJOR LEAGUE BASEBALL
               <br> 
           </div>

           <nav>
              <ul>
                 <li><a class= "menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a class= "menu" href="spelers.php">Spelers</a></li>
                 <li><a class= "menu" href="teams.php">Teams</a></li>
                 <li><a class= "menu" href="wedstrijden.html">Wedstrijden</a></li>
                 <li><a class= "menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>

         <br><br>       
     </div>
     <div id="spelerstabel">
        <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "id1419279_root";
        $password = "nivardenjoey";
        $dbname = "id1419279_mlb";


        $conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT foto, voornaam, achternaam, team FROM spelers";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div id='spelersfoto'> <img class='spelersfoto' src=' " . 
                $row["foto"]. "'/> - Name: " . $row["voornaam"]. " " . $row["achternaam"]. " 
                - Team: " .$row["team"]. " </div>";


            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me please?

*I copied my whole code in here maybe that's easier

Comment: You're using the same ID on every DIV. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @Barmar Although its not valid HTML, this won't prevent the element from being rendered..

Comment: Do you see any HTML being outputted when you view the source code of the website in your webbrowser?

Comment: Have you checked how many rows are you getting? (`print_r($_POST)` if i am not mistaken)

Comment: can't you format code atleast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the space in your `src=' "` argument. Also, please try to have a unique ID. If you need to apply some css to every `div`, use a class instead:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i++;
    echo "<div id='spelersfoto-'".$i."><img class='spelersfoto' src='" . $row["foto"]. "'/> - Name: " . $row["voornaam"]. " " . $row["achternaam"]. " - Team: " .$row["team"]. " </div>";
}
```

Comment: @jm you beat me by two seconds... :) But that said, you do have a point about space in the value for the `src` attribute

Comment: You got my upvote though ;-)

Comment: and you have mine, as your answer was more accurate than mine!

Answer (score 0):

NivardJ,

Try this:

```
$cntr = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div id='spelersfoto-$cntr'> 
              <img class='spelersfoto' src='" . $row["foto"]. "'/>
              - Name: " . $row["voornaam"]. " " . $row["achternaam"]. " 
              - Team: " .$row["team"]. " 
          </div>";
    $cntr++;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Best,

-Rush